# How to call viewcontroller method from AppDelegate if I use TabBar Navigation

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I really need a help with calling view controller method as soon as my app open when the remote notification comes in especially when using TabBar navigation.When I open my app when the notification arrive,it will call **didReceiveRemoteNotification** because I enabled "content-available = 1".But,the problem is I don't know how to access my `HomeViewController` method `refresh()` because I use TabBar Navigation.I need to call `HomeViewController` `refresh()` method inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification` because it really need to refresh the data from core and the notification that arrived are saved at coredata.

Everytime the notification comes in,I save them at realm database and show user at `HomeViewController`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary{
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary{
            if let mbody = alert["body"] as? String{
                print("Message Body : \(body)")
                body = mbody
            }
            if let mtitle = alert["title"] as? String{
                print("Message Title : \(title)")
                title = mtitle
            }
        }
    }

    let newNotification = NotificationList()
    newNotification.title = title
    newNotification.body = body
    //Realm insert query
    oneSignalHelper.insertOneSignalNotification(newNotification)

    print("Remote Receive")
    //This condition isn't working
    if let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? HomeViewController {
        print("Remote Receive Read")
        //This method is HomeViewController method which I gonna use for refresh when I tapped notification.It read that are save in realm database and show results.
        viewController.readNotificationsAndUpdateUI()
    }

    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)

}
```

This is `readNotificationsAndUpdateUI()` from `HomeViewController`

```
func readNotificationsAndUpdateUI(){
    notifications = realm.objects(NotificationList)
    self.notificationTableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    self.notificationTableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using NSNotificationCenter, just post notification inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification` like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refreshNotification", object: nil)
```

In your HomeViewController in `viewDidLoad()` you should subscribe to the notification center like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver( self, selector: "refresh", name: "refreshNotification", object: nil)
```

Comment: Actually I am doing like this,please check my question

Comment: Is HomeViewController your rootviewcontroller? If you have tabbarNavigation i guess UITabBarController is your root, maybe try grabing it `as? ITabBarController`, then get homeViewController from items array from tabbarcontroller. Btw, i dont see you using NSNotificationCenter, it is a different thing from Push Notifications.

Comment: Yeah I am using TabBarController,its the root.But,i dont know how to access HomeViewController refresh method from AppDelegate.

Comment: Sorry, only idea i have is NSNotificationCenter, please note that its not same as Push Notifications (remote notifications). Code i provided in answer should work, just when adding observer, provide selector of method you want to be called when notificationCenter sends notification (not push notif)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but I solved it this way, based on previous answer

Load Storyboard

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
```

Load ViewController (check that you have an identifier in your storyboard for this ViewController!)
    let bestellvorschlag = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Bestellvorschlag") as! Bestellvorschlag

Load Function on ViewController

```
bestellvorschlag.loaddata() //Loads CoreData into Array of artikels
```

Maybe Modify the Tabbar Badge with the number of Results

```
let tabbarcontroller = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    if bestellvorschlag.artikels.count > 0
    {
        if let tabItems = tabbarcontroller.tabBar.items {
            // Third Tab!
            let tabItem = tabItems[2]
            tabItem.badgeValue = bestellvorschlag.artikels.count.description
        }
    }
```

Complete Function in appDelegate

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
 let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let bestellvorschlag = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Bestellvorschlag") as! Bestellvorschlag
        bestellvorschlag.loaddata()

        let tabbarcontroller = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        if bestellvorschlag.artikels.count > 0
        {
            if let tabItems = tabbarcontroller.tabBar.items {
                // Third Tab!
                let tabItem = tabItems[2]
                tabItem.badgeValue = bestellvorschlag.artikels.count.description
            }
        }
    }
```